# Pandas: dropping all columns with nans, 0, and NA from DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan

I have a DataFrame that looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2.1, np.nan, 4.7, 5.6, 6.8],
                'B': [0, np.nan, np.nan, 0, 0, 0],
                'C': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0],
                'D': [5, 5, 5, 5, 5.6, 6.8],
                'E': ['NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA'],})
```

How would I drop all the `NA`, `Nans` and `0` in the columns so I would get the following output?

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2.1, np.nan, 4.7, 5.6, 6.8],
                'D': [5, 5, 5, 5, 5.6, 6.8],})
```

So far I know `.dropna()` will get rid of all the `nan` also I tried `df2=df[~(df==0).all(axis=1)]` and it did not work.

Comment: Do you want to be left with just columns 'C' and 'D' (not 'A' and 'D' as is your example)?

Comment: @ajcr I want just A and D left since they have data that does not have a column with all 0, Nan or NA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> df
     A   B  C    D   E
0  1.0   0  0  5.0  NA
1  2.1 NaN  0  5.0  NA
2  NaN NaN  0  5.0  NA
3  4.7   0  0  5.0  NA
4  5.6   0  0  5.6  NA
5  6.8   0  0  6.8  NA
>>> f = df.replace([0,'NA'], np.nan).apply(lambda x: any(~x.isnull()))
>>> f
A     True
B    False
C    False
D     True
E    False
dtype: bool
>>> df.loc[:,f]
     A    D
0  1.0  5.0
1  2.1  5.0
2  NaN  5.0
3  4.7  5.0
4  5.6  5.6
5  6.8  6.8
```

Answer (score 3):

You could try using `df.isin()` and `all()` to find an array of columns which don't contain only null values and then use this array to select the relevant columns of `df`:

```
>>> df[df.columns[(~df.isin([NaN, 'NA', 0])).all().values]]
     A    D
0  1.0  5.0
1  2.1  5.0
2  NaN  5.0
3  4.7  5.0
4  5.6  5.6
5  6.8  6.8
```

Or more concisely: `df.loc[:, (~df.isin([NaN, 'NA', 0])).all()]`

Comment: You forgot the np in front of NaN